# What is the best practice to implement equality for readonly structs?

Tags: c#, struct, c#-7.2

I've just started to program in C# last year and I'm still learning the language. I have a question regarding [`readonly struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly#readonly-struct-example) type and equality comparison methods.

When creating a struct in C#, I know it's usually considered to be a best practice to implement [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8) as the default reflection-based comparison is very slow. I also learned that in C# 7.2 and later we can define `readonly` structs and for these types, we can also use [`in` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier) to avoid unnecessary copying.

As structs are usually defined as immutable readonly types, I suppose it's not unusual to define Equals methods for read only structs.

Given the above facts, however, what I'm wondering is if there is a good effective way to implement equality comparison methods for them. My point is that none of these equality methods and operators actually need to modify parameters so I want to utilize `in` parameters somehow to save unnecessary copying.

Below is my attempt at doing this:

```
public readonly struct Point : IEquatable<Point>
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    // Explicitly implementing IEquatable<Point> and delegating to an Equals method taking in param.
    bool IEquatable<Point>.Equals(Point other) => Equals(other);

    public bool Equals(in Point other) => X == other.X && Y == other.Y;

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) => obj is Point other && Equals(other);

    public static bool operator ==(in Point left, in Point right) => left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(in Point left, in Point right) => !left.Equals(right);

    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(X, Y);

    public override string ToString() => $"Point({X}, {Y})";
}
```

The above certainly works but I think it's not perfect solution as copying is still needed if it's called through the `IEquatable` interface. Note that I can't just implement `IEquatable` implicitly with `in` param as Equal method taking in modifier is considered to have different signature and treated as an overload.

Is there a known best practice to implement this correctly?
**What I would really like to know is if there is a known best practices and patterns to effectively implement equality for such readonly structs.** Especially I'm interested in a way to properly utilize `in` parameter modifier for implementing Equality comparison methods.

So far I haven't found any satisfactory answer on the Web, and I also checked some source codes of the core library. For example, `System.DateTime` is now defined as readonly struct and it's rather big, but in parameter isn't utilized t here. (Existing type might well need to keep compatibility, I know they often need to have compromise, though.)

Note that the Point struct defined above is small composing only two 32 bit slot, so copying might not actually be a big problem here, but it's just meant for a simple illustrative example.

**Update for .NET6(C# 10)**

Now that C#10 has officially been released, the original question has become almost obsolete. We can now create such a read only struct as an `readonly record struct`. Of course depending of your model, it can also defined as a normal refence type record (class).

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/

The point is that optimized equality comparison methods and operators are automatically generated for record types.

```
    public readonly record struct Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; init; }
        public string LastName { get; init; }
    }
```

Comment: IMO, your code looks just fine. You can have a look at blog post regarding `readonly` structs, like [this](https://montemagno.com/optimizing-c-struct-equality-with-iequatable/), they show the similar approach

Comment: I am not sure if this would work (cannot try it at the moment), but starting with C# 8.0, you can have default implementations in interfaces. This brings to mind the theoretical possibility of having a custom IStructEquatable<T> generic interface and to have a default implementation of the Equals method, comparing the byte representations of the two struct instances (using Marshalling of course). This would help eliminating the need for repeating Equals, GetHashCode methods. Just thinking loudly here.. :)

Comment: By the way, I know that you are compiling against 7.2. As I said, just thinking out loud.

Comment: I personally think  that C# should provide easier way to define immutable structs in future version. Just like anonymous classes, compiler should automagically generate sensible equality implementation by default.

Comment: This question would be better suited on Code review or Software Engineering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above is fine, however: note that the advantages of `in` on read-only value-types only really kicks in for types that are non-trivial in size; in the case of two integers, you're probably over-thinking things.

You can't remove the need to use pass-by-value on the `IEquatable<T>` scenario, since that is how the API is defined.

It may also be worth noting that the `in` usage may make it hard to consume this API from languages other than C#; VB has poor support for this, as an example. Whether this is important depends on your target audience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you it should only be matter for large structs and the simple Point example might not be the best use case for in parameter. In future C# will probably provide easier and efficient way to implement immutable structs.

Comment: @Ryo "records" in c# vNextProbably

Comment: Interesting. I know similar record type is in the latest Java, so it's desirable in C# too. C# already have similar data types such as anonymous class, tuple, but former has no name and heap allocated and latter is mutable. None of them is suitable for domain model's value objects unfortunately.